# NativeScript Could not find module components/Home

Tags: ios, vue.js, nativescript

After creating a vue nativescript app and running via:

```
tns preview
```

I get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: Error: Could not find module './components/Home'

tns doctor
```

gives:

No issues were detected.
✔ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.
✔ Your adb from the Android SDK is correctly installed.
✔ The Android SDK is installed.
✔ A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.
✔ Javac is installed and is configured properly.
✔ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.
✔ Xcode is installed and is configured properly.
✔ xcodeproj is installed and is configured properly.
✔ CocoaPods are installed.
✔ CocoaPods update is not required.
✔ CocoaPods are configured properly.
✔ Your current CocoaPods version is newer than 1.0.0.
✔ Python installed and configured correctly.
✔ The Python 'six' package is found.
✔ Xcode version 10.1.0 satisfies minimum required version 9.
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
✔ Component nativescript has 5.1.0 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-core-modules has 5.1.1 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-android has 5.1.0 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-ios has 5.1.0 version and is up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to add the --bundle parameter

https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/docs-cli/project/testing/preview#options

https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/getting-started/quick-start/

NativeScript-Vue is relatively recent and the [roadmap](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/whats-on-the-nativescript-roadmap-for-2019) points out that the --bundle parameter likely will vanish